# how to send xml packet in SoapUI without method name tag?

Tags: c#, soap, soapui

When i make wsdl file in Soap UI , it shows all web methods on left side , when i click on any method Request ,it shows standard xml Format , with body tag first ,after it shows method name tag, after this it shows tag of parameters we provided to  web method, but i don't want to show method name , i only want to show parameter name. You can better understand with snap shots.

[This is what i am doing ,but i dont want method name tag after body tag as done in 2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtdYE.png)

[In 2nd image which is not my code, it somebody else code, method name is not visble after body tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47wke.png)

Comment: You are changing namespaces.  Why?  It looks like creating a new xml document with different namespaces is going to be easier then modifying an existing xml.

Comment: Sorry for late reply .i was busy with  other works. I am not changinging namespaces , 1st image shows my code , 2nd one is somebody else code and i want to do it as it shown in 2nd image. Just want to show the parameter  passed in web method  in xml body.

Comment: You need to show more of the xml.  The namespace need to be defined.  Neither image shows the beginning of the code where you need to define the namespace before using.

Comment: I have updated images above. As you can see the 1st one is showing my method name "FETCH" then my class name which have one string variable "RequestXml", which will accept whole xml as a string, but in 2nd one there is only one parameter which is taking whole xml as string.